# ok, so another if or condition being met with feet, inches, formatting, and two cells with results

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

ok. so, i have a cell which displays in feet and inches from overall inch length cell is d32 but references p32 which is in overall inch formatt (12 feet equals 144) so the below formula makes the 144 inches say 12'

Cell D32:

```
=CONCATENATE((P32-MOD(P32,12))/12,"'-",ROUNDDOWN(MOD(P32,12),0),IF(MOD(P32,1),
```

Referenced cell is p32:

```
=(((G10*2)/B32)+2)
```

The +2 in the above p32 forumula is for gutter length. The way we figure gutters is there is a 2” waste for splicing two gutters together so we order gutters that are going to be spliced with an additional 2 inches of length. I want to have the formula in such a way as that if in cell B32 has 2 listed as the value or (1 gutter per short side) that is does not add the additional 2 inches that b32 does.

my conditional cell b32, if it has a value of 2, p32 does not add the additional 2 inches. Any value above 2 however must add the additional 2 inches.

see screen cap below...

[workbook snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHsTj.png)

edited mistake about cell locations 11:28AM Central, Please have a second look.

D32 displays the length for each gutter individually, not total span, also most of our projects are on a square or rectangular dimension, so there will never be any less than 2 listed in b32.

Edited 2:37PM 5-26-15

I finally figured it out, this is the end result of P32 that if a value of 2 is entered for b32, that no additional inches are added and that is to subtract out the +2 from earlier in the equation.... See below...

=(((G10*2)/B32)+2)+IF(B32=2,-2,0)

Comment: What happens when a value of less than 2 is in D32?

Comment: Aside from the spelling mistake of columns in your screen shot my only guess is your title.  It reads more like a sentence

Comment: Just noticed your first formula is incomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(B32=2,0,2)
```

The above formula will return 0 when B32 is =2 or 2 when B32 is equal to anything but 2.

You can take that formula and literally replace the 2 in your formula where you add +2 so it would become:

```
=((G10*2)/B32)+IF(B32=2,0,2))
```

[IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) is made up of 3 parts

- Logical
- True result
- False result (optional)

=IF(Logical,True Result, False Result)

---

From Donald Latta:

I finally figured it out, this is the end result of P32 that if a value of 2 is entered for b32, that no additional inches are added and that is to subtract out the +2 from earlier in the equation.... See below...

=(((G10*2)/B32)+2)+IF(B32=2,-2,0)

Comment: Circular Reference Warning. how do i give you sample data from excel?

Comment: Your screen shot is enough.  Let me double check.  I had to run to the dentist earlier but I am back now with a frozen mouth so this is a good task while I wait for feeling to return.

Comment: or... could there be an "IF" statement added to P32 that if cell B32 has a value of 2, to subtract 2 which will give a net result of 0 inches added or subtracted from the overall equation?

Comment: @DonaldLatta yes, you could do that as well, just have to have your math set up to deal with the number that your if statement is going to spit out at you.

Comment: =(((G10*2)/B32)+2)+IF(B32=2,-2,0)

Comment: Got it, thankyou. Glad i found this resource online.

Comment: =(((G10*2)/B32)+2)-IF(B32=2,2,0) would give you the same results.  Just wanted to show you that there are many options.